# How to create you save feature in opencart?

Tags: php, html, opencart

i am trying to show a new feature in the shopping cart and in the mail, it is the you save feature which calculates the total price and total special price and gives the total money saved. that is

```
 total price - total discounted price = you save.
```

I am using opencart 2.0 without vqmod. Can someone help...